# array/list/tuple of nparrays with variable length?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In Python, I have the following problem, made into a toy example:

```
import random
import numpy as np

x_arr = np.array([], dtype = object)
for x in range(5):
    y_arr = np.array([], dtype=object)
    for y in range(5):
        r = random.random()
        if  r < 0.5:
            y_arr = np.append(y_arr,y)
    if random.random() < 0.9:
        x_arr = np.append(x_arr, y_arr)

#This results in
>>> x_arr
array([4, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 3, 4], dtype=object)
```

I would like to have

```
 array([array([4]), array([0, 1, 2, 4]), array([0, 3, 4]), dtype=object)
```

So apparently, in this run 3 out of 5 (variable) times the array $y_arr$ is written into $x_arr$, having lengths 1,4, and 3 (variable).

append() puts the results in one long 1D-structure, where I would like to keep it 2D. Also, considering the example, it might be that no numbers get written at all (if you are 'unlucky' with the random numbers). So i have an a priori unknown array of arrays with, each of those, a priori unknown number of elements. How would I approach this in Python, other than finding an upperbound on both and store a lot of zeros?

Comment: yeah, that seems to work.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do it in a two step process? First add an element, then set the element. This circumvents the automatic flatten which happens in np.append() when axis=None (default behavior), as documented [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html).

```
import random
import numpy as np

x_arr = np.array([], dtype = object).reshape((1,0))
for x in range(5):
    y_arr = np.array([], dtype=np.int32)
    for y in range(5):
        r = random.random()
        if  r < 0.5:
            y_arr = np.append(y_arr,y)
    if random.random() < 0.9:
        x_arr = np.append(x_arr, 0)
        x_arr[-1] = y_arr

print type(x_arr)
print x_arr
```

This gives:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
[array([0, 1, 2]) array([0, 1, 2, 3]) array([0, 1, 4]) array([0, 1, 3, 4])
 array([2, 3])]
```

Also, why not use a python list for x_arr (or y_arr?). Nested numpy arrays are not really useful when they are not ndarrays.

Comment: Indeed, I will go with the list solution, just like @hpaulj mentioned. I do accept your answer since you provide the answer to the original question.